# Import articles from a custom database into wordpress posts

Tags: database, import, wordpress

I want to import categories and articles from my custom database into wordpress categories and posts. Any idea, hint or code snippet will be much appreciated.

Thank You and Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you have to do is to insert your records in `wp_posts` table in Wordpress. This table has the following fields (if you use the latest 3.9.2 version of course):

```
ID - (no explanation needed, it is auto-increment value)
post_author - (here in your case put 1 - this is Administrator account)
post_date - (no explanation needed)
post_date_gmt - (same as above, but date is GMT)
post_content - (your article content, HTML code, if any, may or may not be escaped)
post_title - (no explanation needed)
post_excerpt - (can be empty in your case)
post_status - (there are six of them, in your case put "publish" or "draft" if you want manually to make post visible at later stage)
comment_status - (put "closed" if you want to disable comments or "open" otherwise)
ping_status - (same as above, but it applies for ping)
post_password - (put empty string)
post_name - (put lowercase converted post title, but replace spaces with "-", this is URL friendly version of the post name, ex: my-first-post-title)
to_ping - (put empty string)
pinged  - (put empty string)
post_modified - (put date of the post)
post_modified_gmt - (same as above, but date is GMT)
post_content_filtered - (put empty string)
post_parent - (put 0 initially, later you can build your post hierarchy)
guid - (URL of the post, http://www.yourdomain.com/?page_id=the_ID_of_the_post)
menu_order - (put 0)
post_type - (put "page" or "post", there is a difference though)
post_mime_type - (put empty string)
comment_count - (put empty string)
```

Here is example SQL query with minimum required values for successful insert:

```
INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_author,post_date,post_date_gmt,post_content,post_title,post_excerpt,
post_status,comment_status,ping_status,post_password,post_name,to_ping,pinged,
post_modified,post_modified_gmt,post_content_filtered,post_parent,guid,
menu_order,post_type,post_mime_type,comment_count) 
VALUES (1,'2014-08-28 02:00:00', '2014-08-28 00:00:00','<h1>Some content</h1>',
'My first post','Some excerpt','publish','closed', 'closed','','my-first-post',
'','','2014-08-28 02:00:00', '2014-08-28 00:00:00','',0,
'http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?page_id=2000',0,'post','','')
```

Keep in mind, that your table `wp_posts` may have a prefix.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, it helped me alot.